# python like @property on angularjs model?

Tags: angularjs

Lets say i have simple user resource:

```
angular.module('models', ['ngResource']).
    factory('User', function($resource) {
    var User = $resource('/api/users/:userId', {userId:'@id'}, {});
    return User;
});
```

this might return a user containing `{firstName: 'bob', lastName: 'smith'}`. 
i would like to display the users `fullName` which would be `firstName +' '+ lastName` in my view. How to do do this?

Right now in my controller i have:

```
$scope.user = User.get({userId: 42}); //bob smith
```

But where do i attach the `fullName` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just take the resource and add a new property or method with JavaScript's prototyping.  Since it returns a constructor.

So something like:

```
User.prototype.fullName = function() {
     return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};
```

EDIT: If for some reason that doesn't work... there is a little JavaScript hack for modifying object prototypes hidden by closures: You can use the `.constructor` property of a create object and alter the prototype of that.